# accessing root from the class in Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

It throws the following warning but works in spite of warning.

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at play_fla::MainTimeline/play_fla::frame1()

Here is the working code

```
package {
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*; 
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class ClickButton extends SimpleButton {
    public var fLabel:String;
    public var sName:String;
    public var sNumber:Number;

    public function ClickButton()
    {

    }    

    public function GotoSession(sesBut:SimpleButton, frameLabel:String, sceneName:String):void {           
    sesBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoSes);         
    function gotoSes(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("sesBut = " + sesBut.name);
    trace("frameLabel = " + frameLabel);
    trace("sceneName = " + sceneName);
    trace("this.stage = " + this.stage);
    trace("this.root = " + this.root);
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel, sceneName);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Also it traces the following

sesBut = home, frameLabel = menu, sceneName = Home, this.stage = undefined, this.root = undefined

this.stage and this.root is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why You need to write this class for this purpose, but You may try this anyway to figure You out the issue.

Class ClickButton :

```
package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class ClickButton extends SimpleButton{
        public var fLabel:String;
        public var sName:String;

        function ClickButton() {

        }
        public function GotoSession(sesBut:SimpleButton, frameLabel:String, sceneName:String):void {
            fLabel = frameLabel;
            sName = sceneName;
            trace("sesBut = " + sesBut);
            trace("frameLabel = " + frameLabel);
            trace("sceneName = " + sceneName);
            trace("this.stage = " + this.stage);
            trace("this.root = " + this.root);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Timeline frame 1 :

```
import ClickButton;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

var cb_1ClickButton = new ClickButton();
addChild(cb_1ClickButton);
cb_1ClickButton.GotoSession(new SimpleButton, "frameLabel", "sceneName");
```

Output :

```
sesBut = [object SimpleButton]
frameLabel = frameLabel
sceneName = sceneName
this.stage = [object Stage]
this.root = [object MainTimeline]
```

You may not access the root nor stage until the ClickButton is not Event.ADDED or Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is not effective.
You may only refer to root or stage when the instance is added.

If you figure You out the big picture, You may search and debug this by Yourself. ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you explain me how to add mouse click handler as well as Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE for this.

Comment: Hi, I added EventListener. It works but throws an error, TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Sincerely, I don't understand the meaning of Your Class...
That's my fault / problem.
Why do You want to make a Class that add Listeners to some buttons?
As long Your Class don't extends MovieClip, Sprite or Simple button, DisplayObjectContainer... When You instantiate it, You have no reference to root, nor Stage.
This seems to be a little tricky ...

Comment: Hi, I am an AS2 develper. I am converting my code to AS3. Basically I am coding to switch between scenes by clicking buttons. I am giving frame label sand scene names as arguments. MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel, sceneName); works fine on the stage. But when I use the same on class it throws the warning TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. I know it happens as there is no root for the class. So i would like to refer root from my class. For that also I tried ADDED_TO_STAGE, but it also throws error. But inspite of warning, it works.

Comment: You have 
this.stage = [object Stage] (DisplayObjectContainer)
this.root = [object MainTimeline]  (DisplayObjectContainer)
But no MovieClip I'm speedy for now, so I may be wrong here...
Quick comment...

Comment: Why don't you want to add the Listeners when the button is already added on Stage, or in a Container?
Did You really need a Class to do this? @Rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh If You add A MovieClip with a SimpleButton inside it,
As A MovieClip is dynamic, You may add a property frameLabel:String = The frame Label You want ,  and a var frameLabel:String with the fameLabel You want. You may also add a name to the movieClip, so when an Event occurs, you can deal with the event.target properties and MC properties...
You don't need to write a class for this...?! Yes?
Is that what they ask You to do?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128285/discussion-between-tatactic-and-rajesh).

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. Please check. I am doing it in a class as this code will appear in so many scenes and I do not want to repeat it. So I prefer to pass the scene names as arguments.

Comment: @Rajesh please just forget AS2! :)