# Referring stage from the class Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Basically I am coding to switch between scenes by clicking buttons. I am giving frame label sand scene names as arguments. MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel, sceneName); works fine on the stage. But when I use the same on class it throws the warning TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. I know it happens as there is no root for the class.Is there any way to fix it. Please find the code below.

//class code

```
package {
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*; 
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class ClickButton extends SimpleButton {
    public var fLabel:String;
    public var sName:String;
    public var sNumber:Number;

    public function ClickButton()
    {

    }    

    public function GotoSession(sesBut:SimpleButton, frameLabel:String, sceneName:String):void {           
    sesBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoSes);         
    function gotoSes(event:MouseEvent):void {       
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel, sceneName);
    }
    }
}
```

//AS3 code

```
var btn1 = new ClickButton();
addChild(btn1);
btn1.GotoSession(home, "menu", "Home");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here, and I don't really understand why You work like this but,

1 : When I try to compile your code, I get an compile time Error :

There miss a "}" at the end of Your Class.

I removed what's not used:

```
package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class ClickButton extends SimpleButton {
        public function ClickButton() {
        }
        public function GotoSession(sesBut:SimpleButton,frameLabel:String,sceneName:String):void {
            sesBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSes);
            function gotoSes(event:MouseEvent):void {
                MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel,sceneName);
               // and if You want to remove the ClickButton instance :;
               // ADD those two lines :
               sesBut.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSes);
               MovieClip(root).removeChild(sesBut);
               // DO NOT forget to remove the Listeners before to remove an instance!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that you have a button in Your Library linked to the ClickButton Class as here below:

[image]

So :

```
var btn1:ClickButton = new ClickButton();
addChild(btn1);
btn1.GotoSession(btn1, "menu", "Home");
stop();
```

If I click on btn1, this brings me to the scene "Home" at the label "menu".

This works like a charm.

on the frameLabel "menu" :

```
stop();
trace("currentScene.name = " + this.currentScene.name);
trace("currentFrameLabel = " + this.currentFrameLabel);

/*
OUTPUT : 
currentScene.name = Home
currentFrameLabel = menu
*/
```

[EDIT]

If I set the visibility to false, then again to true, I have the same problem if I want to change the alpha property of mc_1.
This works on my file:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
stop();
trace("currentScene.name = " + this.currentScene.name);
trace("currentFrameLabel = " + this.currentFrameLabel);
var mc_1:MovieClip = mc_1;
// If I don't add this line, I have the same problem when I set the visibility to true
var mc_2:MovieClip = mask_mc;
var mc_3:MovieClip = red_mc;
// I do the same for mc_2 labeled "mask_mc"
// mc_1 is now always recognized as a MovieClip as mc2.
mc_1.visible = false;
mc_1.visible = true;
// No more problem if I add the line var mc_1:MovieClip = mc_1;
// If I don't do this, I cannot access mc_1 as a MovieClip
mc_1.alpha = 0.5;
mc_1.mask = mc_2;
mc_3.alpha = 0.5;
mc_3.visible = false;
mc_3.visible = true;
mc_3.alpha = 0.9;
// It seems that You have to declare the MC variables before to change the properties
```

[/EDIT]

but I don't understand Your line :

```
//btn1.GotoSession(home, "menu", "Home");
```

home is null (You don't have any reference to a ClickButton named home)...???

Comment: Happy for You @Rajesh
I never created a Scene in AS3, so I didn't even now how to create a one, that was the most difficult for me.
But I think that You could improve Your code...

Comment: So that's what You wanted to ask in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603368/accessing-root-from-the-class-in-action-script-3 ? This is more clear now! +1 for your question so.

Comment: Yeah, it was working for me also before. But the error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference came because I had made visibility of some movie clip objects to false i.e., mc1.visible=false, where it lands. When I commented those lines, this warning is not appearing. It is strange.

Comment: The issue seems to be different, I tried this on my file and didn't get any issue where I'm landing  :( mc1.visible=false didn't give me any Error message. I do not understand this issue!
@Rajesh Strange!

Comment: @Rajesh : I edited the answer, I think that the issue is there.
If mc_1 is not explicitly declared as a MovieClip, I cannot change the alpha property. So, no issue if I add var mc_1:MovieClip = mc_1;

Comment: @Rajesh

I even try to add another MovieClip instance name is "mask_mc"
and added the code to my edit.
No problem so far.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I tried your solution i.e., declared movieclip variables and assigned to the movieclips that are on the stage. But some of the movie clips are not becoming invisible. I tried alpha property as well but has the same issue.

Comment: @Rajesh I edited the code a second time and don't found any issue.
This is perhaps another part of Your code... ???

Comment: @Rajesh I really don't understand, I can make what I want with my MC's on the landing frame...

Answer (score 1):

You may also create a ClickSomeButton Class
with a static method "gotoLand"

```
package {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class ClickSomeButton{
    public static function gotoLand(target:MovieClip,sesBut:SimpleButton,frameLabel:String,sceneName:String):void {
            sesBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSes);
            function gotoSes(event:MouseEvent):void {
                target.gotoAndStop(frameLabel,sceneName);
                target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSes);
                target.removeChild(sesBut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your fla :

```
var btn2:Btn2 = new Btn2();
addChild(btn2);
btn2.x = 200;
ClickSomeButton.gotoLand(this,btn2, "menu", "Home")
stop();
```

Symbol properties for Btn2 in the library :

[image: library symbol properties]

This is just because I don't know why You have to pass the Button as a parameter if You call a method of this instance...
Like you did in the original question :

```
//btn1.GotoSession(btn1, "menu", "Home");
```

This is strange in Your ClickButton Class...